# Differences between $Session variable and Getter/Setter

Tags: php

Using $Session variable or Getter/Setter, which one is better to store information and use it globally ?

Answer (score 0):

Getter/Setter is a concept in class and doesn't have anything to do with being global per se.

Comment: Then what I can use for handling data globally ? I am thinking to use SESSION Variable or something like singleton design pattern

Comment: You can use session.